# WebSocket Request: 426 Upgrade required

Tags: websocket, paw-app

I'm a licensed user of the ***Paw 2.2.7*** Rest client and I would like to issue a WebSocket request.

I currently get back the response: ***426 Upgrade Required***. I would like to define a proper WebSocket request within the client.

Is it possible? If so, how would I define such a request?

Comment: Unfortunately we do not support WebSockets yet. But as I don't think there's a good tool for testing them, we will probably find a way to add them to a later version of Paw (plus we are starting to use WebSockets for our server work, so we will need a testing tool internally too!). Thanks!

Comment: is there somewhere you might have feature backlog or a UserVoice that users can indicate preference for new features?

Comment: @MichaMazaheri Please answer to question above. I'm also interesting in this future.

Comment: No we don't really have a "UserVoice" on this yet. We keep track of these ideas on our internal issue tracker. But please stay tuned, we may have something nice for WebSockets coming in the not-so-far future :)

Comment: Is this being worked on?